# Passing an arraylist in array-android app

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, arrays

I have been referring this app to make a gallery module
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

However according to the requirement in my app the images are dynamically added.So, I am fetching all the images via JSON.The image response from JSON Iam adding in the arraylist.

How should I pass "`image_urls.add(folio.getString(i));`" in the new class :

```
public class Test extends Activity{

    private static String url = "http://www.xyz.com/album_pro/array_to_encode";

     JSONArray folio = null;
     ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
              StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            {

            try{

                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                Log.v("URL",json.toString());

            JSONObject seo = json.getJSONObject("SEO");
            Log.v("seo",seo.toString());
            JSONArray folio = seo.getJSONArray("Folio");
            ArrayList<String> image_urls = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0;i< folio.length();i++)
            {

                image_urls.add(folio.getString(i));

            }


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
}

}
```

How should I pass "`image_urls.add(folio.getString(i));`" in a non activity class named "Images"
i.e

```
public class Images {
    public final static String[] imageUrls = new String[] {
      **Required the arraylist of "Test" activity**

    };
    public final static String[] imageThumbUrls = new String[] {

         **Required the arraylist of "Test" activity**
    };

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov : How should I pass "image_urls.add(folio.getString(i));" in the new class i.e

Comment: @Shweta : where is new class ? in use class constructor if new class is an non activity class

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : its a non activity class

Comment: @Shweta use ArrayList instead of Array...And get create a method to add elements to the ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Make the `ArrayList` `public` and `static` and use it in other class as `Test.urlList`

Answer (score 1):

Make the `Images` members non-final so that you can set them at runtime.

After your loop which add image urls to `image_urls` ArrayList, set the properties of `Images` class:

```
Images.imageUrls = image_urls.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to make the `image_urls` as public static. since it contains only urls right? only small amount of data and in the Image class access that with

```
Test.image_urls.get(integer);
```